# C# equivalent to Java's charAt()?

Tags: c#, java, string

I know we can use the `charAt()` method in Java get an individual character in a string by specifying its position. Is there an equivalent method in C#?

Comment: Are you looking for a solution that only works on strings guaranteed not to contain any non-16-bit Unicode characters? Or are you looking for a solution that works on an arbitrary string?

Answer (score 245, accepted):

You can index into a string in C# like an array, and you get the character at that index.

Example:

In Java, you would say

```
str.charAt(8);
```

In C#, you would say

```
str[8];
```

Comment: I think it should be pointed out that str.Substring(8,1) works as a solution, but it is much slower. Just found that out the hard way.

Answer (score 23):

```
string sample = "ratty";
Console.WriteLine(sample[0]);
```

And

<strike>`Console.WriteLine(sample.Chars(0));`

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.chars%28v=VS.71%29.aspx</strike>

The above is same as using indexers in c#.

Answer (score 1):

In C#, the string must be static for saying :

str[8];

Answer (score 0):

you can use LINQ

```
string abc = "abc";
char getresult = abc.Where((item, index) => index == 2).Single();
```

Answer (score -1):

please try to make it as a character

```
string str = "Tigger";
//then str[0] will return 'T' not "T"
```

Answer (score -3):

`Console.WriteLine` allows the user to specify a position in a string.

See below sample code:

```
string str = "Tigger";
Console.WriteLine( str[0] ); //returns "T";
Console.WriteLine( str[2] ); //returns "g";
```

There you go!

Answer (score -4):

Simply use `String.ElementAt()`. It's quite similar to java's `String.charAt()`. Have fun coding!

Comment: Why would you use an IEnumerable extension method, when you can just do what the others mentioned many years ago? (Built-in string indexing).