# How extract a specific character in a string in c# by index

Tags: c#, string

In c++ strings are like array when you write str[i] you can acsess i+1 element of array in there something like that in c# I do not need indexOf method because that is different I need something to bring characters in string by their index

Comment: It seems to be exactly the same according to [this post.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3581741/c-sharp-equivalent-to-javas-charat)

Comment: see [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.chars(v=vs.100).aspx]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, you can reference characters of a string using the same syntax as C++, like this:

```
string myString = "dummy";
char x = myString[3];
```

Note: `x` would be assigned `m`.

You can also iterate using a `for` loop, like this:

```
char y;
for (int i = 0; i < myString.Length; i ++)
{
    y = myString[i];
}
```

Finally, you can use the `foreach` loop to get a value already cast to a `char`, like this:

```
foreach(char z in myString)
{
    // z is already a char so you can just use it here, no need to cast
}
```

Answer (score 7):

It's just the same in C#: `s[n]` gets you character number `n` of string `s`.