# Getting character at a particular index in a string c#

Tags: c#, string

Just like the GetAt method of the CString type in C++, whats the equivalent function in c# to get the character at a particular index in a string?

Comment: Atleast justify the downvote!

Comment: you are supposed to do minimum efforts before posting : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3581741/c-sharp-equivalent-to-javas-charat

Comment: This kind of question you should just Google :/

Comment: Stop! Please have mercy! Can I delete this question and get my points back?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
string myString = "HelloWorld";
char myChar = myString[index];
```

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
string result = mystring[myindex].ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

Like an array:

```
var s = "hello";
var ch = s[0]; // ch == 'h'
```

Answer (score 0):

Treat the string as an array.

```
var testString = "blah";
Console.WriteLine(testString[2]);
```

Writes...

```
a
```