# UPDATE Keyword Equivalence From Java to C#

Tags: c#, java

I am converting code from Java to C#, but having issues figuring out some keyword equivalence. I have looked over the web and can't find anything. Updated added number 3.

1) Does anyone know what C# uses for charAt()? Below is how I am trying to use it.

```
 curr = tokens[i].charAt(0);
```

2) Also having issues converting isEmpty() to C# syntax.

```
 if (par.isEmpty())
```

3) How should I convert this:

```
op2 = compute.pop().intValue();
```

Thanks!

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3581741/c-sharp-equivalent-to-javas-charat

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/3581751/3383479

Answer (score 3):

1) Strings can have their characters accessed by using the [] operator:

```
curr = (tokens[i])[0];
```

2) IsEmpty becomes `String.IsNullOrEmpty` or `String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace` depending on what you want (the second is only available in .NET 4+ as well).

3) From what research I could find, it looks like intValue deals with boxing/unboxing. If you stick with working with ints, you shouldn't need to worry about that in C#. "Pop" will work the same if you have a Stack collection. Hopefully that gives you enough to convert the line.

Comment: what are the _parentheses_ for ?

Comment: @Selman22 Because I felt like it :). It makes it clear that it is taking the string out of the tokens array, then you are applying the [] operator to that string. The other way looks like it could be a multi-dimensional string array. Obviously the syntax would be valid for both cases. Do you think it looks better without them?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `tokens[i]` is a `string`, treat the string as an array of characters:

```
var firstCharacter = tokens[i][0];
```

Assuming `par` is also a string, the [`string.IsNullOrEmpty()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorempty.aspx) method can help you test whether or not a particular string is empty:

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(par))
{
}
```

If `par` is a `Stack<String>` as you've indicated, then you could test whether it was empty (has no elements) with a simple bit of LINQ:

```
if (!par.Any())
{
    // par has no elements
}
```

Alternatively, you could use the `Count` property in the `Stack` class:

```
if (par.Count == 0)
{
    // par has no elements
}
```

Comment: How would I do this if par is a stack. For example, I have this above: Stack<String> par = new Stack<String>();

Answer (score 1):

1) In `C#` a *string* is also an array of characters.So you can access a character using the indexer:

```
curr  = tokens[i][0]
```

2) You can compare your string with `string.Empty` or use `String.IsNullOrEmpty` method to check whether a string is empty or not:

```
if( par == string.Empty )
```

OR:

```
if( string.IsNullOrEmpty(par) );
```

Comment: How would I do this if par is a stack. For example, I have this above: Stack<String> par = new Stack<String>();

Answer (score 1):

A different approach:

1) You can use `curr = tokens[i].ElementAt(0);` This will return the same result as charAt(0)

2) `if( string.IsNullOrEmpty(par) );` will do the job.