# Similar function charAt of Java in C#

Tags: c#

I have Java code

string[] elementMath = { something }

```
elementMath[i].charAt(0);
```

In C# , i have try with

```
elementMatn[i][0];
```

But it will give me error

Comment: what `type` is elementMath

Comment: object reference is null

Comment: what's elementMath[i]'s datatype?

Comment: is String array

Comment: Is `elementMatn` correct? Or you mistyped it? And what kind of error do you get?

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: array is not initialised or string at zero location is null

Comment: "`elementMatn[i][0];`" This should be correct, I can´t see why an eror should occur. Please post the error and stracktrace (if existing).

Comment: @viveknuna Sure it is, see the first code-line. Unlike `something` is not null, your comment is misleading.

Comment: something is not a string , so how can I be sure what he/she wants to ask?

Comment: BTW [C# equivalent to Java's charAt()?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3581751/3796048) is stating that you are writing it correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is probably somthing wrong wth your array initialization.
Here is a working example with the same syntax as yours:

```
  string[] elementMath = new [] {"aa", "bb", "cc"};
  char result = elementMath[1][0]; // result is 'b'
```

Answer (score -1):

In C#, strings are also an array of char.
If the element is not null you could use indexing or `string.ElementAt(index)`.

```
string[] arr = string[]{ "testA", "testB", "testC" };
char c1 = arr[0].ElementAt(4);  // c1 will be 'A'
char c2 = arr[1][4]; // c2 will be 'B'
```