# String compare not possible in C#

Tags: c#

Please solve the problem of C # code.
There is no comparison of blanks(" ").

```
string a = "I am a boy.";

for(int i=0; i < a.Length; i++)
{
    if(a[i].Equals(" "))
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("blank!");
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Not blank!");
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to compare with char: `if (a[i].Equals(' '))`

Comment: you can compare   `if (char.IsWhiteSpace(a[i])) `

Comment: check this link @J.Sung

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3581741/c-sharp-equivalent-to-javas-charat @J.Sung

Comment: @styx while your statement is true, your solution will not satisfy the same requirements. IsWhiteSpace will not only be true for "space". Just to throw in some nitpicking.

Comment: @Fildor can you give an example?

Comment: @styx See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char.iswhitespace(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_1 but to name some: "Line feed", "Tab" ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are comparig a `char` to a `string`. Simply put `' '` does not equal `" "`.

Change `if(a[i].Equals(" "))` to `if(a[i].Equals(' '))` and you should get your expected result.