# How do I check if string contains char at specific location?

Tags: c#

I want to be able to check for a specific character within a string that the location is being pointed at. For example in Java you would do `if (b.charAt(bPointer) == '#')` expect i'm coding in c#. I'm wondering if i possibly should be using the `contains()` method or `indexOf()` method or is there a different way I'm suppose to be doing this.

```
public static bool func(string a, string b)
        {
            int aPointer = a.Length - 1;
            int bPointer = b.Length - 1;

            int aSkips = 0;
            int bSkips = 0;

            while(aPointer >= 0 || bPointer >=0)
            {
                while (aPointer >= 0)
                {
                    if (// check if a.CharAt(aPointer) =='#' )
                    {
                        aSkips += 1;
                        aPointer -= 1;
                    }
                    else if (aSkips > 0)
                    {
                        aPointer -= 1;
                        aSkips -= 1;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }

                while (bPointer >= 0)
                {
                    if ()
                    {
                        bSkips += 1;
                        bPointer -= 1;
                    }
                    else if (bSkips > 0)
                    {
                        bPointer -= 1;
                        bSkips -= 1;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
```

Comment: `if (s[index] == '#')`. You might want to confirm that `index < s.Length` first though.

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed thats that worked perfectly. I should of thought of that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3581741/c-sharp-equivalent-to-javas-charat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the indexer:

```
if (a[aPointer] == '#')
```

You may want to check the length of the `string` to avoid getting an [`IndexOutOfRangeException`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.indexoutofrangeexception):

```
if (aPointer < a.Length && a[aPointer] == '#')
```

Comment: I would check the string length first, to prevent index out of range exception