# Detecting variables outside method

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I was trying to make a 2d Unity Latin translator, but i got a problem. How could i make that it recognises the Text and Dropdown variables already inside the "Declinatio". I need to check for the last 2 characters of this string which is SGenTextStr, and the data should be taken from the SGenText InputField. I dont know if you got a fix for this, i didnt find anything that was helpful on the internet.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine.UI;
public class LatinDecl : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static void Declinatio()
    {
        string SGenTextStr;
        string AnsTextStr;
        int StrLength;
        SGenTextStr = SGenText.text;
        AnsTextStr = AnsText.text;
        StrLength = SGenTextStr.Length();
        switch (SGenTextStr.charAt(StrLength - 2) + SGenTextStr.charAt(StrLength - 1))
        {
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

    }
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        InputField SGenText;
        Dropdown DeclDrop;
        InputField AnsText;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the things you may use a lot in Unity games is the [`Gameobject.GetComponent<>()` method.](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponent.html) It allows you to access values and functions from other components or scripts in your Unity Scene.

There are also an issue with declaring your variables in `Update()` as it will cause them to be wiped clean every frame, instead you may want to move them outside all together.

Because of that you will also have trouble with `Declinatio()` as it is currently static, which wont allow it to reference any non-static variables outside of it.

The last issue is that C# doesn't actually have an implementation of `String.charat()` however you can use [`String[int]` to achieve the same thing.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3581741/c-sharp-equivalent-to-javas-charat)

With all those changes it would look something like this:

```cs
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine.UI;
public class LatinDecl : MonoBehaviour
{
    public InputField SGenText;
    public Dropdown DeclDrop;
    public InputField AnsText;

    public void Declinatio()
    {
        string SGenTextStr;
        string AnsTextStr;
        int StrLength;
        SGenTextStr = SGenText.GetComponent<InputField>().text;
        AnsTextStr = AnsText.GetComponent<InputField>().text;
        StrLength = SGenTextStr.Length;
        switch (SGenTextStr[(StrLength - 2)] + SGenTextStr[(StrLength - 1)])
        {
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

    }
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Just one more thing: how could i take the input from the Dropdown to be usable as a string?

Comment: Oh and why is that the first closed curly bracket is counted as the ending bracket of the whole code?

Comment: As for the Dropdown check out this page about `Dropdown.value` https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.4/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.Dropdown-value.html

The first curly bracket is the start of the Class. As a good practice most programmers will declare their variables in that first space so they're easy to find and available throughout the class